# prepare() failed; error coming when trying to prepare SQL statement in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

> prepare() failed;

This error is coming when I try to prepare this SQL statement:

```
$stmt = $statement_handler->prepare( $sqlQuery );
```

echo of `$sqlQuery` is:

```
 SELECT
 distinct(reservation.reservationid),reservation.name,reservation.age
 as p_age,reservation.gender as
 p_gender,reservation.lessonregistrationno,reservation.mobile,reservation.email,reservation.arrivaldate,reservation.arrivaltime,reservation.departuredate,reservation.departuretime,centers.name
 as
 centername,reservation.purposeofvisitid,reservation.otherpurpose,reservation.additionalinformation,reservation.status,reservation.membertype
 as
 type,reservation.iskriyaban,reservation.sharedacco,reservation.citizenship,reservation.total_guest,reservation.created,reservationmember.name
 as
 member_name,reservationmember.age,reservationmember.lessonregistrationnumber,reservationmember.gender,reservationmember.membertype,relationships.relationship,countries.name
 as country,purposeofvisits.purpose FROM reservation LEFT JOIN centers
 ON reservation.centerid = centers.centerid LEFT JOIN purposeofvisits
 on purposeofvisits.purposeofvisitid = reservation.purposeofvisitid
 LEFT JOIN countries ON countries.id = reservation.countryid LEFT JOIN
 reservationmember on reservationmember.reservationid =
 reservation.reservationid LEFT JOIN relationships on
 reservationmember.relationshipid = relationships.relationshipid WHERE
 1 AND ( (reservation.arrivaldate >= '2016-10-01') ) AND (
 (reservation.arrivaldate <= '2016-10-10') ) ORDER BY
 reservation.status desc, reservation.arrivaldate asc,
 reservation.reservationid asc LIMIT 0, 25
```

Backend is MySQL and frontend is PHP.

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: `WHERE 1` what is the need?

Comment: prepare() failed; This error is coming when I try to prepare this SQL.

Comment: `Prepare() failed` isn't a PHP error message. Try again.

Comment: prepare() failed is the error that is coming.

Comment: Then try that query directly in MySQL and see what error that gives you.

Comment: yes, run your query in phpmyadmin.

Comment: The parens around `reservation.reservationid` (following the `DISTINCT` keyword) are superfluous. DISTINCT is *not* a function. It's a keyword, that  applies to the entire list of expressions in the SELECT list. It doesn't give one whit about the parens.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the `$stmt_handler` class, and specifically look at the `prepare` function.

My guess is that in that function, there's a check for an error condition, and it is echoing out the text message "prepare() failed".

If this was this is being output as the result of an error reported by MySQL, the actual error message would be available from MySQL. Either from the [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) function (if the code is using mysqli_) or the [`PDO::errorinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) function (if the code is using PDO.)

Use that to get the actual error returned from MySQL.

Also, take the SQL text to another client, and test it there. Any other client you run the statement in isn't going to "hide" a SQL error.

We're just guessing that the error you are seeing is related to a problem in the the SQL statement. There are a large number of possible reasons MySQL can return an error... not connected to the database, insufficient user privileges, not in the correct database, table doesn't exist, column references are invalid, syntax error, etc.

There no glaring syntax problems that I can see. There's some funkiness, but I don't see anything invalid. All the column references are qualified, so collision with a reserved word shouldn't be an issue.